# use ExoMedia and Google VR in one apk

Tags: android, video, virtual-reality, exoplayer

I want to play both `VR` video and normal video in a one android app.
I used google `VR` to play `VR` videos and everything is okay.
but when I want to play normal video, I see something like *fisheye*.
So now I want to use `ExoMedia` for normal videos.
but when I add `ExoMedia` to `gradle` and run the app I see below error.

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/exoplayer/AspectRatioFrameLayout;

I used below dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:common')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:commonwidget')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:panowidget')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:videowidget')
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:3.0.1'
}
```